# Issue when using react-native-ble-manager and nodejs bleno on raspbarry pi3

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, react-native, raspberry-pi

I need to connect my **phone** to **Raspberry**
via **Bluetooth**, get list of **available wifi**, choose one on the phone, send it's it to Raspberry and connect to selected network.

I've chosen **'react-native-ble-manager'** for react-native and **bleno** for raspberry.

After connection to Raspberry with my phone I'm trying to BleManager.read but **readData** that responds is empty String

**Raspberry** for Characteristics:

```
onReadRequest(offset, callback) => {
    callback(Characteristic.RESULT_SUCCESS, new Buffer('Hello'));
  });
},
```

**React Native:**

```
BleManager.read(peripheralInfo.id, '12AB', '34CD')
            .then((readData) => {
                // Success code
                console.log('Read:', readData);
            })
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, and what should I change to send my message from mobile-app to the raspberry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not send more than 20 character at a time in BLE. So if you has large string, than data must be sent in 20 bytes chunk. This chunking is already implemented in react-native-ble-manager. So if you have string of more than than 20 character, then you will receive multiple onWriteRequest callback in periferal. You must handle that callback properly.

Comment: I am using this with `IOS` but not able read/write data without `nrf connect app` to establish connection